# XML parsing with ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I was wondering if it's possible to use the existing text in a tag to get the text on the next tag in the XML tree considering the following XML file:

```
...
<link>
   <description>document</description>
   <url>https://www.../doc/file.pdf</url>
</link>
<link>
   <description>document1</description>
   <url>https://www.../doc1/file1.pdf</url>
</link>
<link>
   <description>document2</description>
   <url>https://www.../doc2/file2.pdf</url>
</link>
...                     
    
    for item in tree.findall('.//subChapter//document//link//'):
        if item.tag == 'description':
            if item.text == 'document':
                **THEN GET THE TEXT ON THE NEXT TAG <url>...</url>**
                **e.g: https://www.../doc/file.pdf**
                print(NEXT TAG)
            elif item.text == 'document1':
                **THEN GET THE TEXT ON THE NEXT TAG <url>...</url>**
                **e.g: https://www..../doc/file1.pdf**
                print(NEXT TAG)
            elif item.text == 'document2':
                **THEN GET THE TEXT ON THE NEXT TAG <url>...</url>**
                **e.g: https://www.../doc/file2.pdf**
                print(NEXT TAG)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using lxml parser it could be doable by using getnext() function. When using ElementTree this could be achievable by changing the loop:

```
# iterate over link elements
for link in tree.findall('.//subChapter//document/link'):
    # keep reference to link child elements
    children = list(link)
    for item in children:
        if item.tag == 'description':
            if item.text == 'document':
                # acess necessary link child by index
                next_tag = children[1]
                print(next_tag.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solution works flawlessly. I would take a look at the lxml parser.